# How to fix WARNING: use of system property netbeans.home has been obsoleted

Tags: java, netbeans, warnings, netbeans-platform, obsolete

This is the complete message:

WARNING [org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager]: use of system property netbeans.home has been obsoleted in favor of InstalledFileLocator/Places at org.netbeans.Clusters.relativeDirsWithHome(Clusters.java:137)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a documented bug in Netbeans Platform 7.4:

["Bug 226333 - Prevent warning about use of system property netbeans.user"](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=226333)

The bug is reported fixed in a nightly build in February 2013. However, my team is still seeing this warning despite the fact that we downloaded 7.4 in December 2013 and have applied all subsequent updates. Therefore I think the easiest fix would be to [upgrade to version 8.0](https://netbeans.org/downloads/).

I was going to suggest that you could also [download the 7.4 source code](https://netbeans.org/community/sources/) and override the appropriate Utils.java class in the Versioning module to apply the fix by Ondrej Vrabec that is documented [here](http://hg.netbeans.org/main-golden/rev/a0d53e2abab7). However the class is final, so an upgrade appears to be the only option.

Comment: I have the version 8.0 and the warning persists